# Is it possible to specify doctype in Visualforce components ?

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, css, html5

Is is possible to specify DOCTYPE in Salesforce visual force components?
How can DOCTYPE affect the responsiveness of the component (If we have given some styling/responsiveness to the UI)

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: did you try or read the documentation? Please limit your posts to only 1 question as mentioned in [ask] Thanks

Comment: You can only add that attribute to pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML only allows a single DOCTYPE for a page. Accordingly, you cannot specify a DOCTYPE for a single element. DOCTYPE will generally have little effect on performance, but may cause other complications. For example, if you use an XHTML DOCTYPE, you'll be forced to verify all your code is perfectly XHTML compliant or the entire page will fail to load. Generally speaking, you should use either no DOCTYPE (for HTML4), or HTML5. Other types tend to be quirky and may cause undesirable graphical glitches or parsing errors.

Comment: thanks ! 
So, If I have some problem viewing the responsiveness of the component in a mobile, can this be solved using a doctype ?
Because, as we cannot use this in visual force component what can be the solution for this?

Comment: @kkbandi No, changing the DOCTYPE won't likely fix anything. If a component isn't responsive, it's likely a CSS problem.